# Error when inserting value into fmdb

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert, insert-update, fmdb

What I coded is below:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO usercart (id, productid, name, description, campaignid, startdate, enddate, martid, martname, price, update) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(int)cartItem.databaseId,(int)cartItem.itemId,cartItem.itemName,cartItem.itemDescription,(int)cartItem.campaignId,cartItem.campaignStartDate,cartItem.campaignEndDate,(int)cartItem.martId,cartItem.martName,(int)cartItem.itemPrice,cartItem.lastUpdate]
```

And I got an erorr and message below :

```
DB Error: 1 "near "update": syntax error"
DB Query: INSERT INTO usercart (id, productid, name, description, campaignid, startdate, enddate, martid, martname, price, update) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
DB Path: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F08F458-BAB3-4523-B942-68ABF67CACF6/Documents/HaffleMonster.sqlite
Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near "update": syntax error" UserInfo=0x170e65740 {NSLocalizedDescription=near "update": syntax error}
near "update": syntax error
```

I don't know why. I think i am right with syntax of sqlite and fmdb Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `update` as a variable name since it's used by SQL. Just like you can't use `insert` or `into` as variable names.

You either need to change the variable name or encapsulate it with `[]`, like this `[update]`. So that it reads:

```
...price, [update]) VALUES (?,?,?...
```

Comment: But after editing table and inserting code, i got an error : Could not find index for all columns. Can you explain why? I think I confront another problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with FMDB. It sounds like you need to add an index for the new column you created. If that doesn't work I would revert back to what you had before (the `update` column) and just change it to `[update]` in the query.